# How to specify more than 1 condition with && for a property in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I need to specify more than one condition for visibilty

```
visible="{data.allow && data.open}"
```

However, this gives the error "The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference."

I could use a function, but I'd like to know if it is possible to do this directly with different syntax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `&` is a special character in XML, you have to encode the `&` as `&amp;`, so your expression would become `visible="{data.allow &amp;&amp; data.open}"`.

Read more in the Flex Help chapter ["Specifying special characters in the text property"](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d53.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf63fd7-8000).

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot, splash especially for the additional resource.